# Obtain android registration ID for GCM using php

Tags: android, zend-framework, google-cloud-messaging

I'm going round in circles trying to figure this out. Have push notifications working fine for iOS now trying to do same with android GCM. I'm stuck on how to expose a service which allows me to gather a users registartionID. Using java is a real pain on my server so a php only solution would be useful. 
My notification script is looking like this so far:

```
require_once('config.php');
require_once 'Zend/Mobile/Push/Gcm.php';
require_once 'Zend/Mobile/Push/Message/Gcm.php';

$con = mysql_connect($CONFIG['db']['host'] , $CONFIG['db']['user'], $CONFIG['db']['pass']);
if (!$con) {
  echo "DBConnectionError: Could not connect to database";
}

$db = mysql_select_db($CONFIG['db']['database'], $con);
if (!$db) {
  echo "DBSelectError: Could not select database";
}

// optain list of devices to send pn to
$qt = "SELECT uid userid, apntoken "
    . "FROM members "
    . "WHERE apntoken IS NOT NULL "
    . "AND uid IN ("
    .   "SELECT fuid userid "
    .   "FROM avail "
    .   "WHERE apnsent IS NOT TRUE "
    .   "UNION "
    .   "SELECT uid userid "
    .   "FROM availbinary "
    .   "WHERE apnsent IS NOT TRUE "
    .   ") ";

//send gcm message
    $message = new Zend_Mobile_Push_Message_Gcm();
    $message->setId(time());
    $message->addToken($tokenRec['apntoken']);
    $message->setData($alert);

    $gcm = new Zend_Mobile_Push_Gcm();
    $gcm->setApiKey('AIzaSyCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxnFn5mGkM');

    try {
        $response = $gcm->send($message);
    } catch (Zend_Mobile_Push_Exception $e) {
        // all other exceptions only require action to be sent or implementation of exponential backoff.
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a POST method on your php for the user to 'upload' their registration_id. There are tons of tutorial on how to expose a PHP POST request. Let's say the URI of this POST request is `http://yourserver/gcm/send_reg_id`, and the Content-Type of this body can be anything you want (text, json, xml). Let's say you go with json, your app will send a POST request to the above url, with the following body:

```
{ "reg_id" : "asdadsafdsf34ZXZZZZx", "user_id" : "xxxxxx" }
```

Your server will extract the above json string from the POST request body, and insert the reg_id to your database.

Then in your app, it's just a matter of using the gcm-client.jar library, and upon receiving the onRegistered() callback, send the above POST request to your server.

There are a few things to consider:

1. Make the request https to be secure
2. Add 'user_id' to track registration by user, to provide personalized push notification in the future.